# python trim number without converting to string first

Tags: python

if i have an integer like this:

123456789

I would like to return only 12345 - so trimming the number to a length of 5 digits.

Is this possible without first converting to a string? I cant see any built in function to do this.

Comment: can the number have any arbitrary length?

Comment: Yes, it can be any length - i have only provided the example to illustrate the problem

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Trimming a number to an arbitrary length means nothing. Trimming a string representation of a number makes a little more sense (although not much). My point being that if you're going to truncate a number like that, convert it to a string first. If you just want all the numbers to be less than a certain value, use the modulo function: `1234567 % 99999`.

Comment: Also, what are the first five digits of `-123456789`? Is it `-1234`? `12345`? An error?

Comment: Without knowing the range of input types and expected output it seems that `int(str(12345678)[0:5])` is the simplest and most readable.  Why are you trying to avoid strings?

Comment: I suppose `int(unicode(123456789)[:5])` fits the letter of the question for Python 2.x. For 3.x… you could need to write a function that can render an `int` as an encoded ASCII or UTF-8 `bytes` or `bytearray` without going through `str`, but that seems even sillier.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```py
import math

def five_digits(number):
    ndigits = int(math.log10(number))+1
    try:
        return number//int(10**(ndigits-5))
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        return number

print five_digits(10000000)
print five_digits(12345678)
print five_digits(12345)
print five_digits(1234)  #don't know what you want to do with this one...
```

Comment: This returns `1234` for `1234`, and raises a `ValueError: math domain error` for `-123456789` or `0`, and (in 2.x) returns `12345L` even though it could return `12345` for `12345678901234567890`. But I think all of those are reasonable things to do, given the sparse information the OP gave. Except maybe for `0`.

Comment: @abarnert -- Thanks for pointing out all of my deficiencies.  All of those could be hacked around using `if` statements if necessary. e.g. `if negative, return -four_digits(abs(number))`, etc.

Comment: Well, they're not deficiencies; you can't be expected to show the cartesian product of all possibilities for all possible ambiguous features in the question. I just thought it was worth mentioning them—as you say, you can easily work around any of them if you want to make a different choice, but you have to actually realize there's a choice and make it before you can do so…

Answer (score 1):

For example:

```
number = 123456789
while number >= 10**6:
    number = number/10

#wrapped in a function for n arbitrary
def trim_to_n(number, n):
    negative = False
    if number < 0:
        negative = True
        number = number * -1
    limit = 10**(n+1)
    while number >= limit:
        number = number/10
    if negative:
        return number * -1
    return number
```

**UPDATED:** For negative values :D

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: You need `while number >= 10**(n+1)` (using `>=` instead of `>`). Also, in the function it would make sense to calculate `10**(n+1)` once instead of each time through the loop.

Comment: Nice heads up :) I wasn't thinking in optimization, and you're completely right about `>=`. Fixing the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Use integer division(//)
123456789 // 10000 will return 12345.